# Can't display full text in input box (php)

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'login';
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(!$conn){
    die('Connection failed.');
}
else{
    if(!mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname)){
        die ('Unable to connect to database.');
    }
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM login_info';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo "<h1>List</h1>";
echo "<table border = '2px' align = 'center'>
<tr>
    <th colspan='1'>ID</th>
    <th colspan='1'>Userame</th>
    <th colspan='2'>Password</th>
    <th colspan='2' align='center'>Operation</th>
</tr>";
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<form action = 'tEdit.php' method = 'POST'>";
        echo "<tr align='center'>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type = 'text' name = 'id' value = " . $data['id'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type = 'text' name = 'name' value = " . $data['username'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type = 'text' name = 'psw' value = " . $data['password'] . " < /td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'hidden' value = ". $data['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type = 'submit' name = 'update' class = 'update' value = 'Update'" . "< /td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type = 'submit' name = 'delete' class = 'delete' value = 'Delete'" . "</td>";
        echo "</form>";
}
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Here's my problem: When I run this program, in the input box it would display the data/texts that are from my database. However, it does not display a text where there's a space between two words. [Example: From my database, the 'username' is John Smith, but when displayed, it only displays John, and Smith is nowhere to be found.] Can anyone help me so that the data/texts in the input box would display in full? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
  echo "<td>" . "<input type = 'text' name = 'name' value = " . $data['username'] . " </td>";
```

To

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type = 'text' name = 'name' value = '". $data['username']. "'   </td>";
```

Your output will be :
[image]

The problem is you didn't quote your value. Look closely in what is the difference in the code I've given compared to yours, you'll figure it out.